# μ-recursive (mu-recursive) function in a functional language

Tags: functional-programming

I am wondering how to write [μ-recursive function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C-recursive_function) in any functional programming language?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question? Every function you write in a functional language is mu-recursive.

Comment: Oh. I was confused. What I meant is the _minimization operator μ_, described in [WP article above](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C-recursive_function#Definition): "Intuitively, minimisation finds the smallest argument that causes the function to return zero, providing that the function is defined for all smaller arguments." Is this an obvious iteration from 0 to the first x that makes f(x)=0? (for a unary function f).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, as far as I know, precisely what you gave. Iterate over all arguments until you hit one that returns zero. For functions of more than one argument, you diagonalize. i.e., (0,0), (1,0), (0,1), (1,1), (2,0), (2,1), (0,2), (1,2), (2,2), etc.